# Unity Build performance issues with build

Tags: unity-game-engine, leap-motion

I'm running a unity build (simple graphics with Leap Motion) on a MacBookPro 2012 on Windows (installed native on an external drive). This build runs super fast, no issues.

When I run the same build on the latest Windows machine with dedicated graphic card, it runs half the performance (fps) than the 7 years old machine. Is there a specific setting for Windows machine or so...?

In the editor it runs smooth on both machines, only the compiled build isn't working well. I tried to compile on the latest Windows machine, but same result :(

Setup:
- Unity 2018.9
- Leap Motion Orion 4.x

Comment: If you can build it, why not open the profiler to find the answer?

Comment: I found the problem, in the log file. The issue was with the new notebook has a switchable graphics and wasn't using it for some weird reason. At the end it was a Windows problem - graphic settings ;)

You can specify in the settings, which app is using which card.